# Can't import name 'sync_playwright' from 'playwright.sync_api' on MacOS and ubutunOS

Tags: python, playwright

I'm trying import playwright framework. However, I faced an issue as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 1, in <module>
    from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
ImportError: cannot import name 'sync_playwright' from 'playwright.sync_api' (/home/acid/dev/play/venv
/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_api.py)
```

I've installed the playwright by command below:

```
pip install playwright==1.8.0a1
playwright install
```

Then, run script:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

    with sync_playwright() as p:
        for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
            browser = browser_type.launch()
            page = browser.new_page()
            page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/')
            page.screenshot(path=f'example-{browser_type.name}.png')
            browser.close()
```

However, it still didn't work.
Do you have any suggest for this issue?
Thank in advances

Comment: Not python proficient, but I played with that a few days ago. Are you sure that pip is installing playwright on python 3.8 and not in 2.7 (default on mac)?

Comment: I've tried run by python3 playwright.py, even set python3.8 version default on mac, It still was error.

Answer (score 8):

[mxschmitt said on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/1058):

> the problem *might* be that your file is named `playwright.py`, maybe try renaming it to `trying_playwright.py` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Referencing [this](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro):

1. ```shell
   pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
2. ```shell
   pip uninstall playwright
   ```
3. ```shell
   pip install playwright
   ```
4. Change to your script directory
5. ```shell
   playwright install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue, this helped:

1. sudo npm install -g playwright
2. sudo pip install playwright
3. playwright install